# How to get results from prepared statment without using getresult?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

You may think this question is not up to the mark. But i have to post it here... :(

```
$stmt->get_results
```

is not working in my hosting server as the mysqlind is not available there.
i have completed my projects without knowing this and its killing me now...

To overcome this i have created the below function and its working fine. As you can see this function is returning array. Now i am trying to create the exact object which $stmt->get_results return. ie i need to use fetch_assoc() with the object. Other wise i have to edit a large number of files that will kill my time :(.. if somebody can help me pls...

```
 private function getMyResult($stmt)
 {  
    $result = array();

    $metadata = $stmt->result_metadata();

    $data['result']=$metadata; echo "<br/>-------------<br/>1";

    /*while ($myrow = $data['result']->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        print_r($myrow);
    }*/

    $fields = $metadata->fetch_fields();
    print_r($metadata);
    for (;;)
    {
        $pointers = array();
        $row = new stdClass();

        $pointers[] = $stmt;
        foreach ($fields as $field)
        {
            $fieldname = $field->name;
            $pointers[] = &$row->$fieldname;
        }

        call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_result', $pointers);

        if (!$stmt->fetch())
            break;

        $result[] = $row;
    }

    $metadata->free();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I think you'll need to look at the mysqli source to see how to create a `mysqli_result` object from outside the extension. It might not even be possible if the constructor is not public.

Comment: @Barmar both get_results and result_metadata giving same output when i am printint the obj. **mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 9 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 2 [type] => 0 )** only difference is for result_metadata type=1

Comment: You could create your own class `My_mysqli_result`. It could contain an array of all the results, and you can define a `fetch_assoc` method that does what you want.